# SQL - Finding Highest average marks of the students

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to display the maximum average marks; however, I can't seem to get it to work.

I can get the average marks to display using:

```
select max(avg_mark)
from (select round(avg(value),2) as avg_mark from mark;
```

[image: Schema diagram for reference]

The output I am getting = 82.73

Expected Output = 85.67

I am not sure where I am going wrong, am I supposed to round the max(avg_mark) like shown below

```
select round(max(avg_mark),2)
from (select avg(value) as avg_mark from mark;
```

Comment: hi, Please provide input data

Comment: Hey, I cannot view the testing data, that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED POST:

WORKING ANSWER:

Alright got it working. It doesn't need too much hassle

```
select round(max(avg(value)),2) as avg_mark from mark group by student_id;
```

Round function to specify decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work with the right subquery:

```
select max(avg_mark)
from (select round(avg(value), 2) as avg_mark
      from mark
      group by student_id
     ) sm;
```

I am not a fan of Oracle's nested aggregation functions -- it is non-standard and not adopted by any other database.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what are the changes if new column student _id needs to be displayed. Can this query work for that?

Comment: @Mithun . . . You would have a different question and I would recommend asking a *new* question.  Your question here is quite explicitly:  "I am trying to display the maximum average marks".